# A function with only removable discontinuities

Tags: calculus, limits

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776578/if-f-has-only-removable-discontinuities-show-that-f-can-be-adjusted-to-a-co) question that I asked, a helpful user ended his answer with two exercises. I'm not sure what he was intending with them. In particular, the second one seems ill-posed. Is anyone able to discern his meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the second exercise

***Exercise 2***: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable except at $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{y\to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ exists, then prove that $f$ can be "adjusted to a differentiable function".

I agree with you that the exercise is not well formed. Such a function is already differentiable; no adjustment needed.

---

The first exercise was a suggested generalization of

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is such that each discontinuity of $f$ is removable, i.e. $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ exists for all $x$. Define $g(x) := \lim_{y\to x}f(x)$. Show that $g$ is continuous.
>
> ***Exercise 1***: Generalise this result to the case of a function $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary topological spaces (with no further conditions such as first countability).

I interpret the limit condition as follows: for every $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that for every neighborhood $V$ of $y$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U\setminus\{x\})\subset V$. Define $g:X\to Y$ by $g(x)=y$. Then the claim is that the map defined by $g(x)=y$ is continuous.

To verify the claim, take an open set $V$ in $Y$. Observe that $g(x)\in V$ if and only if there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U\setminus\{x\})\subset V$. This implies $U\subset g^{-1}(V)$. Hence,  $g^{-1}(V)$ is open.

Comment: Ah, that's very well said. I had not thought of interpreting the limit condition in that way. :)

Comment: Why does $f(U \setminus \{x\})\subset V \implies U \subset g^{-1}(V)$? Although the values of $f$ lie in $V$ on the set $U \setminus \{x\}$, how do we know that their limits lie in $V$ (since $V$ is not closed)? For instance, consider $$f: x\mapsto \begin{cases}\cos x & x \neq 0 \\ 2 & x=0 \end{cases}\\g: x\mapsto \cos x.$$Then $f((-\pi/2,\pi/2))\subset (-1,1)$, but $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \not \subset g^{-1}((-1,1))$.

Comment: @EricAuld Hm, it was a while since I wrote that. Maybe I need to assume that every point of $X$ is a closed set; this is true in all topological spaces I care about. Then the set $U\setminus \{x\}$ is open, so it is a neighborhood of every point $y$ that it contains. And since $f(U\setminus\{x\})\subset V$, we have $g(y)\in V$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how you make the step to say $g(y)\in V$. Why couldn't $g(y)$ be in $\overline{V}\setminus V$? Suppose $$f:x\mapsto \begin{cases}\cos x & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}\\g:x\mapsto \cos x.$$ Then let $V=(-1,1),$ which is a neighborhood of $g(\pi/6)$. Now $f((-\pi/2, \pi/2)\setminus \{\pi/6\}) \subset V$ but $g(0) \not\in V$.