# A topological function with only removable discontinuities

Tags: general-topology, limits, continuity

*I've posted similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776578/if-f-has-only-removable-discontinuities-show-that-f-can-be-adjusted-to-a-co) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784426/a-function-with-only-removable-discontinuities/815353#comment1834688_815353), but no one has answered them to my satisfaction.*

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ exists for all $x$, that is, $f$ has only removable discontinuities. Then I claim the function $g: x\mapsto \lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ is continuous (see the first link above for a proof).

I was wondering how we might extend this to a function $f:X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Suppose that besides just existing, $\lim_{y \to x}f(y)$ is unique for all $x$. (Or if we assume $Y$ is Hausdorff, we get that for free.)  Is $g:x\mapsto \lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ continuous? Here's a partial result I've gotten:

**Proposition:** Suppose $f$ is as above, and $Y$ has the following property:

$$\tag{1} \text{For every open set $V$ and every point $y\in V$, there }\\ \text{ exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $\overline{U}\subseteq V$.}$$

Then $g$ is continuous.

**Proof:** Let $V$ be open in $Y$, and let $x\in g^{-1}(V)$. Take $U \ni g(x)$ as above. Then the definition of $g$ implies that there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $x$ such that $f(\mathcal{N} \setminus \{x\})\subseteq U$. Now $\lim_{z\to \xi}f(z)$ must lie in $\overline{U}$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{N}$, so $g(\mathcal{N})\subseteq \overline{U}\subseteq V.\quad \blacksquare$

What are the simplest kinds of topological spaces that have property $(1)$? Can we do with a weaker assumption?

Comment: Isn't property (1) equivalent to regularity?

Comment: I think it is equivalent. Just Google "regular topological space" and you'll find many examples.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Indeed it is! That is a a good piece of information. Now, need a space be regular for the conclusion to be true?

Comment: An arbitrary function between spaces with trivial topologies works. Unless you meant the closure of U to be a proper subset...

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I think you should add that comment as an answer, even if it's not a full answer for the question!

Comment: An indiscrete space is $T_3$ or regular, whatever is weaker in your nomenclature. So the trivial topology is just a case known to work.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your proof. I don't see how to justify the conclusion "Now $\lim_{z\to \xi}f(z)$ must lie in $\overline{U}$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{N}$" without assuming that $X$ is a T1 space. In fact there seem to be easy counterexamples where $X$ is an indiscrete space with two points.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen I am interested to hear a specific counter-example. Here's my thinking: form a directed set $\{U_i, \eta_i\}_{i\in I}$ of all the neighborhoods of $\xi$, with a tag on each one, and form a net by $(U_i, \eta_i)\mapsto f(\eta_i)$. Now $\lim_{z\to \xi}f(z)$ is the limit of this net. A point is in $\overline{U}$ iff there exists a net in $U$ converging to it.

Comment: Example: Let $X = \{0, 1\}$ with the indiscrete topology, and $Y = \{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $f(x) = x$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 0$, hence $g(x) = 1-x$ which is not continuous.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen The limit is not unique in that case, so $g$ is not well-defined. Note $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) =0$ also.

Comment: Then your definition of the limit of a function at a point must be different from all the ones that I have ever seen. Perhaps you should include it in the question.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen What's your definition?

Comment: Eric: His notion of limit is the same is yours and in his example the limit is unique and is as Niels wrote. Just follow the definition.

Answer (score 4):

Note that property $(1)$ is just equivalent to regularity, so we already know many examples of spaces for which the proposition holds.

Answer (score 1):

If you require the limit to be unique (as you said, like if we assume $Y$ to be Hausdorff), then $g$ must be continuous.

First, the function $g$ is defined everywhere, since the limit of $f$ exists and is unique everywhere. Now you have to show that the limit of $g$ exitst (and is unique, but that's implied by the Hausdorff assumption) and that it matches the value of the function. Well, assume the limit does not exist at a point $x_0$. Then,

$$\exists V\subset Y\ \text{ s.t. }\ g(x_0)\in V, \text{ and }\, \forall U\subset X \,\, \exists y_U\in U \,\,  \text{s.t. } g(y_U)\notin V\tag{1}$$

To fix ideas, if $X,Y$ were also metric spaces, this would mean

$$
\exists \varepsilon>0 \text{ s.t. } \forall \delta>0\ \exists x_\varepsilon \,\text{ s.t. }\, |x_\varepsilon-x_0|<\delta, |g(x_\varepsilon)-g(x_0)|>\varepsilon.
$$

Given this set $V$, by definition of limit (and the definition of $g$), there is $U\subset X$ s.t. $\forall x\in U$, $f(x)\in V$. However, by (1), there is $y_U\in U$ s.t. $g(y_U)\notin V$. There are two scenarios: $g(y_U)\notin \partial V$ and $g(y_U)\in \partial V$.

1) If $g(y_U)\notin \partial V$, then $g(y_U)\in (\overline{V})^c$ and, by definition of $g$ as limit of $f$, $\exists U_y\subset U$ such that $y_U\in U_y$ and $f(x)\notin V\ \forall x\in U_y$, which contradicts the fact that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists.

2) If $g(y_U)\in\partial V$, then consider $W\subset V$ such that $g(y_U)\notin \overline{W}$ (I believe this is possible, because $Y$ is Hausdorff, but you may want to double check this assumption). Then, by definition of limit at $x_0$, we have $Z\subset U$ such that $\forall x\in Z, f(x)\in W$. On the other hand, because of (1), we have that there is $y_W\in Z$ such that $g(y_W)\notin V$, and therefore $g(y_W)\notin \overline{W}$. Hence, we can use part 1) to conclude.

By the same argument I think you should be able to prove that the limit as $x\to x_0$ of $g$ has to be $g(x_0)$.

Edit: the proof was correct only if $g(y_U)\notin \bar{V}$. I added a proof for the case $g(y_U)\in\partial V$.

Comment: I think you're onto something. I'm not convinced by your claim that "by definition of limit", there is $U\subset X$ s.t. $\forall x \in U,\, f(x) \in V$. Remember that the limit takes no notice of what happens at a single point, so we must formulate our definition in terms of "there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U\setminus \{x\})\subset V$", or alternately, "for every net $x_i$, such that $x_i \neq x\,\, \forall i$, we have $f(x_i)$ converging to the same point."

Comment: I learned that your definition of the limit is another one that is in use, and so your proof is correct with that characterization of the limit. With my definition, the proof would have to be different.

Comment: I think your proof has alerted me to an important fact: to speak about $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ existing for all x, we must require that singleton sets are not open. Otherwise the notion of a limit really doesn't make sense (there are no nets of points non-equal to x which converge to x, and the null set is a punctured neighborhood of x, so every point in the codomain is a valid choice for limy→xf(x)). Even still, with such a requirement, I am unable to make a version of your proof go forward.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant $\forall x \in U\setminus \{x_0\}$. That slipped in somehow. ;-)

Notice that singletons are indeed closed, since they contain all limit points of sequences that lie in the set (which, of course, can only be constant sequences, with elements equal to the singleton element).

Comment: Why do you assume $y_U \not\in \overline{V}$? (Note this is necessary for your $U_y$ to exist.) Also, I believe that if $X$ is not a Hausdorff space, it is not necessary that $\{x\}$ be closed (e.g. the indiscrete topology).

Comment: Why you say that I need that? I'm thinking but I can't see it.

Yes, if $X$ is not Hausdorff, then what I said is not true.

Comment: Because you want to choose a neighborhood around $y_U$ which is disjoint from $V$. This is possible iff $y_U \not\in \overline{V}$.

Comment: I guess you meant $g(y_U)\in \overline{V}$ (notice that $V\subset Y$, while $y_U\in X$). You had a strong point there. I modified the proof, to distinguish between the two cases. I'm 99% sure it works now, but you may want to double check.

Comment: Note that the property you mention ($\exists W \subset V$ s.t. $\overline{W}\subset V$) is the condition I mention above in the question, and that condition is equivalent to regularity (stronger than the Hausdorff condition).

Comment: I think you're right. It seems an obvious requirement, but that's because I think about nice topological (and actually metric) spaces.

Comment: $\overline W$ does not have to be contained in $V$ for the proof to go through. It suffices that $g(y_U)\notin\overline W$, and I think this is indeed possible if $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @BenediktvonSeelstrang Could you explain why such is possible please?

Comment: There are disjoint open neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $g(y_U)$ and $g(x_0)$, respectively. Take $W$ to be the intersection of $V$ and $U_2$. Then $g(y_U)\in U_1\subset(Y-\overline{U_2})\subset(Y-\overline W)$, so $g(y_U)\notin\overline W$.